# Ajuda pra arredondar valor retornado da função

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, gostaria que o retorno das variáveis fosse de apenas 2 casa decimais, como faço isso?

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<h1>DESCONTO ETANOL</h1>

<script>

    function pulaLinha() {

        document.write("<br>");
    }

    function mostra(frase) {

        document.write(frase);
        pulaLinha();
        pulaLinha();
    }

    var valorDoAbastecimento = parseInt(prompt("Digite o valor do abastecimento")) ;

    var totalDeLitrosAbastecido = valorDoAbastecimento / 3.09

    var descontoPorLitro = 0.04 ;

    var totalDesconto = totalDeLitrosAbastecido * descontoPorLitro ;

    var dinheiroPago = parseInt(prompt("Digite o valor pago em dinheiro."));

    var valorTotalComDesconto = valorDoAbastecimento - totalDesconto

    var troco = dinheiroPago - valorTotalComDesconto;



    mostra ("<b>O total de litros abastecido é de: </b><mark>" + totalDeLitrosAbastecido + " Litros") ;
    mostra ("</mark><b>O valor do desconto nesta compra é de </b><mark>" + totalDesconto + " R$");
    mostra ("</mark><b>O troco do cliente é de </b><mark>" + troco + " R$");

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar **dois métodos já prontos**, os quais são:

> **a)** `Number​.prototype​.toFixed();`
>
> **b)** `Number​.prototype​.toLocale​String();`

**Sobre o método** `Number​.prototype​.toFixed()`

> O **método** `toFixed()` **formata um número utilizando notação de ponto fixo**. Uma `string` representando `numObj` que não usa notação exponencial e tem exatamente dígitos depois da casa decimal. O número será arredondado se necessário, e será adicionado zeros a parte após a virgula para que este tenha o tamanho que foi especificado. Se o `numObj` for maior que `1e+21`, então será invocado o método `Number.prototype.toString()` e será retornado uma string em notação exponencial.

**Exemplo:**

```
var numObj = 12345.6789;

numObj.toFixed();       // Retorna '12346': note o arredondamento, não possui nenhuma parte fracionária
numObj.toFixed(1);      // Retorna '12345.7': note o arredondamento
numObj.toFixed(6);      // Retorna '12345.678900': note que adicionou zeros
(1.23e+20).toFixed(2);  // Retorna '123000000000000000000.00'
(1.23e-10).toFixed(2);  // Retorna '0.00'
2.34.toFixed(1);        // Retorna '2.3'
2.35.toFixed(1);        // Retorna '2.4'. Note que arredonda para cima neste caso.
-2.34.toFixed(1);       // Retorna -2.3 (devido à precedência do operador, literais de números negativos não retornam uma string...)
(-2.34).toFixed(1);     // Retorna '-2.3' (...a menos que se utilize parênteses)
```

**Sobre o método** `Number​.prototype​.toLocale​String()`

> O **método** `toLocaleString()` **retorna uma string com uma representação sensível a linguagem deste número**. Os novos argumentos `locales` e `options` permitem às aplicações especificar a linguagem cujas convenções de formatações serão utilizadas e personalizar o comportamento da função. Nas implementações anteriores, que ignorava os argumentos `locales` e `options arguments`, a localização utilizada e a forma de retornar a string eram totalmente dependente da implementação.

**Exemplo:**

```
var numero = 123456.789;

// O alemão usa vírgula como separador de decimal e ponto para milhares
console.log(numero.toLocaleString('de-DE'));
// → 123.456,789

// O árabe usa dígitos Árabes Orientais em muitos países que falam árabe
console.log(numero.toLocaleString('ar-EG'));
// → ١٢٣٤٥٦٫٧٨٩

// A Índia usa separadores de milhares/cem mil/dez milhões
console.log(numero.toLocaleString('en-IN'));
// → 1,23,456.789

// A chave de extensão nu requer um sistema de numeração, ex. decimal chinês
console.log(numero.toLocaleString('zh-Hans-CN-u-nu-hanidec'));
// → 一二三,四五六.七八九

// Quando informada uma língua sem suporte, como balinês,
// inclua uma língua reseva, neste caso indonésio
console.log(numero.toLocaleString(['ban', 'id']));
// → 123.456,789
```

Acesse as fontes oficiais abaixo para saber mais como funciona os métodos, são super interessantes e para casos diferentes!

[FONTE OFICIAL - DEVELOPER MOZILLA (Number​.prototype​.toLocale​String())](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

[FONTE OFICIAL - DEVELOPER MOZILLA (Number​.prototype​.toFixed())](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Answer (score 0):

Tente adicionar isso no final do seu código:

```
troco = troco.toFixed(2);
console.log(troco);
```